# Repeat expression until it has reached the end of parenthesis?

Tags: regex, expression, regex-group

I have been working in Regx101 and have been messing around with expressions however I cannot figure out how to repeat an expression until a certain character (ending parenthesis ')' ) is reached.

I have tried [^)]* and it works but it does not repeat the expression.

> This is my expression so far:
>   CREATE\s+TABLE\s+(\w*)(\s+(\w*)\s+(\w*)[,][^)]*

I am trying to get the (\s+(\w*)\s+(\w*)[,] part to repeat until the end of a parenthesis is reached.

> My test string is:
>   CREATE TABLE tableName(columnName, type, primary, columnName2, type2)

These are the results I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iQtj.png)

Expected results should include column2 and type2 as their own individual group.

Any help is welcomed as well as any solutions I have not tried yet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with sample data that you are trying to match and your expected results. A link to your regex101 sandbox would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what exactly you want, but this example

```
echo 'CREATE TABLE tableName(columnName, type, primary, columnName2, type2)' \
| perl -nle '/CREATE\s+TABLE\s+(\w*)\s*\((\s*(\s*\w+ *,)+(\s*\w+)?)/ && print "$1\n$2"'
```

or this slightly more readable version with the `/x` modifier

```
echo 'CREATE TABLE tableName(columnName, type, primary, columnName2, type2)' \
| perl -nle '/CREATE\s+TABLE\s+(\w*) \s* \( (\s*(\s*\w+\s*,)+ (\s*\w+)? )/x && print "$1\n$2"'
```

give this output

```
tableName
columnName, type, primary, columnName2, type2
```